# Listen to event in library module in android

Tags: android

Hello everyone my Question is I have some module and I imported it in other project is there a way to listen for events in that module e.g clicking ,entering data ...etc I need any generic way cause I will use that module in other projectS too.

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be add your own listeners or a event or publish & subscribe framework to the module. Which you would need to do anyway.

For events use an EventBus like `https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus`

For publish/subscribe : use RxJava/RxAndroid/RxBinding

```
// RX Java/Android
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
// https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
// https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
```

I would say the publish/subscribe (RxJava) is more future proof if you are using a library.

Comment: First of all thanks its first time I hear about EventBus  and subscriber it looks useful in many ways .
secondly , I got the idea but what difference between using EventBus and using normal broadcast intent and receivers I mean I need something generic  in the lib module itself so I won't register every time I use it .

Comment: You subscribe to event bus event in the receiver the shared module only needs to publish the events. e.g. EventBus.getDefault().post(updateBetSlipCountEvent); is the module. EventBus is just a bit easier to passing information and objects. Its also a bit easier to trace as it uses objects and methods which you can do findUsages on in the Studio IDE